# Alternative Query String C# (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net-2.0, c#-2.0, query-string

Is there a quick and dirty way of using a query passed as follows:

domain.com/mypage.aspx/product/toycar/

I've done it before in PHP, but this needs to be done in page (in this instance).

--
I only have access to the aspx page and code behind, and have to work in asp.net 2 *(i wish i was using 3.5)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
public class ModuleRewriter : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The url will look like: http://domain.com/mypage.aspx/product/toycar/ 
        // The module will rewrite it to: http://domain.com/mypage.aspx?product=toycar

        HttpApplication application = source as HttpApplication;
        string[] urlInfo = application.Request.RawUrl.ToString().Split('/');
        if (urlInfo.Length > 2)
        {
            string page = urlInfo[urlInfo.Length - 3];
            string action = urlInfo[urlInfo.Length - 2];
            string id = urlInfo[urlInfo.Length - 1];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(page))
            {
                page = "default.aspx";
            }
            application.Server.Transfer(string.Format(
                "~/{0}?{1}={2}", page, action, id));
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ModuleRewriter" type="ModuleRewriter, MyWebApplication"/>
</httpModules>
```

and a test page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%= Request["product"] %>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, you need to register the module somewhere. You can do it programmatically in global.asax (in the Application_Start event) if you don't like web.config.

Comment: Were getting isapi-rewrite, I just wondered if I could achieve the same with IIS/.net as I could with an Apache/PHP setup. Obviously I can, just not as easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the ASP.NET System.Web.Routing namespace, which was added in .NET 3.5 SP1 I believe:

http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/05/14/using-asp-net-routing-independent-of-mvc.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.aspx

You'd be able to get rid of the .aspx extension too.

Comment: Thanks, I'd read the msdn link already. Unfortunatly I'm stuck with what I'm using which is .net 2 and only having access to the aspx file.

Answer (score 1):

This would involve making a custom HTTP Handler.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to read the path from within your .aspx:

Request.ServerVariables["PATH_INFO"]

To clarify:

he has only access to the aspx (+ codebehind) itself, so he must know how the query is, but it is not in the Request.QueryString because of the format. So the only way then is Request.ServerVariables["PATH_INFO"] (Request.RawUrl)

Comment: Thanks for that, useful; but I expect I'll have to resort to mithering them when we get the isapi rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few options, but all of them require access to the web.config and a change to IIS to map all file extensions to the dotNet ISAPI dll:

1. Use MVC (like stackoverflow does,
   notice the urls)
2. Use asp.net routing (new in 3.5)
3. Write your own http handler [Massive guide from Microsoft here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)
4. Use the excellent [urlrewriting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net) which does just about everything perfectly including getting round some awkward authentication and image path problems.

Personally I used urlrewriting.net with good results.

Since you mention you don't have access to anything but the code behind and the page, the only thing I can think of is actually creating those dirs (if you have access to do that) and using a server.transfer page passing the value to your actual page in the folder above.  Messy, but if you can't access the other stuff, your choices are limited.